# Suppress an error message box appearing in Delphi for a specific error

Tags: delphi

At the moment I have a Delphi form running and upon losing connection to its Database/loss of network, it re-establishes and carries on.

The service is on a timer and each minute, it pops up with message box saying failure to connected to db on network [ip address]. This is at the start of the timer, a stored proc is ran.

I have all errors writing to a log file on the service local machine, is there a way I can suppress the message box appearing as I don't need it to appear all the time? by message box it is a windows exception box not a showMessageBox(). It automatically pops up when the exception hits but it will continuously hit whilst the machine boots up and re-establishes connection to the network.

The code I have is as follows

```
    (*Call db Procedure*)
            try
              db.SQL.Clear;
              db.SQL.Add('call dbProc();');
              db.ExecSQL;
            except
              On E : Exception Do
              begin
                If E.ClassName = 'EIBInterBaseError' Then
                  begin
                    WriteToLog('Network Error : An error has occured whilst trying to communicate with the db outside the'
                          + ' loop to catch up , please see user guide V.1.0.2.145',2);
                    reconnectdb;
                  end
                  else if E.ClassName = 'EADOError' then
                  begin
                    WriteToLog('Network Error : An error has occured whilst trying to communicate with the db outside the'
                          + ' loop to catch up , please see user guide V.1.0.2.145',2);
                    reconnectDB;
                  end;
                end;
            end;
```

Comment: In modern versions of Windows (post-XP) services can't readily show UI. In any case, services should not show UI. So one wonders how you are showing UI. And then, if you don't want to show the UI, why are you showing it. UI doesn't happen by accident. It is always explicit. You may have inherited it, but it is still explicit. So, you are going to need to tell us more details. Let's start with understanding how you managed to show UI.

Comment: David, let me rephrase my question as I realise service might have been the wrong word to use here. I'm running a delphi form application on a machine which acts as our data processor across database on separate networks (we use a delphi form as we display statistical information about the contents in the database). Thats where the UI but comes in. When one of the machines on the network is switched off/restarted, I initialise a reconnect procedure and during this time, the service still runs and gives error messages regarding connection loss, each minute till it connects,

Comment: All the same, the message to you is the same. You are explicitly showing UI. You ask us how not to show UI. The answer can only be, "stop showing UI".

Comment: In any case, the correct answer here is not to suppress the message box *once it appears*, the correct answer is to make sure it doesn't appear in the first place.

Comment: each loop presenting an error message saying it cannot connect to the db on that network (as the machine is restarting).

Comment: If you need to add information to your post, [edit] your post to do so, instead of burying it in comments. We don't know what *each loop presenting an error message* means, because **we can't see the code that you're talking about**. If you want help here, explain the problem clearly, include the relevant code, and ask a specific question.

Comment: I don't know how many more times I'm going to need to say this. If you don't want UI to appear, don't show it.

Comment: Your error handling looks badly askew. Not only do you catch all exceptions, you don't appear to handle ones you do catch correctly. Your reconnection attempts likely fail too. Checking class name is wrong. Check exception type with `is`. Or use `on E: SomeExceptionClass`. Anyway, it's too messy for me to give you advice. Remy's advice just sends you further down the dead end.

Comment: As for your code, I expect `reconnectdb` raises an error which is handled by the app exception handler because you don't handle it. You probably haven't realised that once inside an except block, code in the except block can raise.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description (since you did not show any code), it sounds like each iteration of your loop is raising an exception that you are not catching, so it ends up in a default exception handler within the RTL that is then displaying the popup MessageBox.  If this is the case, you need to catch the original exception using a `try..except` block around your code that is failing.

Comment: That might be one way of dealing with it. Another might to to avoid raising the exception in the first place. There could be many other options.

Comment: including assigning your own exception handler to `Application.OnException` but even that isn't the appropriate solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan appologies for any frustration I may have caused in not clearly explaining the problem, could you please look at my amended question and see if this explains the issue a bit better?

also Ken, I have altered the question body,